# Finding the number of time a particular number in a file where range also specified

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I have a file with numbers separated by `,`(comma). In between it also contains a number range like `300-400`. Say for example I have a text file, namely `testme.txt` which looks like,

```
200,300,234,340-350,400,360,333-339
409-420
4444-31231231
348
```

I want to find out whether number `348` is present or not. 348 is present in 2 places:

- 340-350
- In last line.

How to find it?. I tried using `regex` in sed,awk, but I am not able to completely write the script to capture the number range. Is there any other way to find it?

UPDATE: Found 1 brute force solution & it's working only for range.

```
count=0;
num1=348;
for i in `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\-[0-9]\+\)/:&:/g' testme.txt  | 
    awk -F: '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~/[0-9]+-[0-9]+/){print $i} }'`;      
do 
    lh=`echo $i | awk -F\- '{print $1}'`; 
    rh=`echo $i | awk -F\- '{print $2}'`;  
    if [ $lh -le $num1 -a $rh -ge $num1 ]; 
    then  
        count=`expr $count + 1`; 
    fi; 
done
echo $count;
```

Comment: `400;360` or `400,360`?

Comment: yeah its 400,360. Changing it.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot handle range of values easily. You should do numerical comparisons in a language that supports them (even awk can do that, and by setting `FS` you can split at both space and comma).

Answer (score 4):

A GNU awk solution that treats `,` or `\n` as a record separator and `-` as a field separator. An equality check or a range check is applied depending on number of fields

```
awk -v num=348 -v RS=',|\n' -F'-' 'NF == 2 && $1 <= num && $2 >= num{c++};
           NF == 1 && $0 == num{c++};
           END{print c+0}' file
2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -F',' -anle '
for (@F) {
    ($l,$h) = split "-";                
    $count++ if $l == 348 || ($l < 348 and $h >= 348);
}
END {print $count}
' file
2
```

Comment: Your script doesn't give the right answer if one replaces the first comma by a dash.

Comment: Take the example given by the OP, then replace the first comma (between 200 and 300) by a dash. Your script gives 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @vinc17: Sorry, my bad, forget to add the loop, fixed.

Comment: `for (@F) { ($l,$h) = split "-"; defined $h or $h = $l; $count++ if (sort {$a <=> $b} $l,348,$h)[1] == 348; } END {print $count}` is shorter and more robust (if you have 348-348 in the file).

Comment: There is more than one way to do it! See my updated.

Comment: Your new code is incorrect if you have 340-348. Change `$h > 348` to `$h >= 348`?

Comment: @vinc17: mistypo, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will provide the *fields* that contain the specified number, not just the *lines*, if you are after that level of detail (and if the ranges in your data might contain overlaps):

```
awk -v num=348 -F, '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i == num || (split($i, a, /-/) == 2 && (a[1] <= num && num <= a[2]))) {
      print $i
    }
  }
}' <<END
200,300,234,340-350,400,360,333-339
409-420
4444-31231231
348
1-400,100-1000
END
```

```
340-350
348
1-400
100-1000
```

For giggles, golfed:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==n||(split($i,a,/-/)==2&&a[1]<=n&&n<=a[2]))print $i}' n=348 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible method to approach the problem (as there are I am sure many ways to get this done) is to simplify the checks for the number.

Use nested if statements to move through the logic, naturally splitting the 'values' to check based on a comma delimeter.

If the value has a "-" then for the check, split the two numbers at the "-". Then it is a simple matter of checking to see if the number you are checking for is greater than or equal to the first number AND less than or equal to the second number. This will denote it is in the range.

For values without a "-" it is a simple check to see if it is equal.

Perhaps not an elegant approach, but it would get the job done (it seemed to me that you were looking for the method to get at the comparisons and not for the finished script itself, so I am hoping the above provides you with that brainstorming).

Answer (score 0):

This example uses function match.

`awk -F ',' '{num = 348; i = 0; while(i <= NF) {i++; match($i,/([0-9]+)-?([0-9]*)/,arr); if(arr[1] == num || (arr[1] <= num && num <= arr[2])){count++}}} END {print count}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is wellformed, file with list and number as parameter, this should work in PHP:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach(explode("\n",file_get_contents($argv[1])) as $line)
foreach(explode(",",$line) as $cols)
{
    $data = split(',',$cols);
    if(((count($data)>0)&&($data[0]==$argv[2])) ||
        (count($data)>1)&&(($data[0]-$argv[2])*($data[1]-$argv[2]) < 0))
        count++;
}
echo $count;
```

put the code in a file script.php and call it from bash like this:

```
php script.php testme.txt 348
```